# How to avoid clearing the cache after every CSS change?

Tags: theming, caching

[image]

I use D7 and I'm tired of clearing the cache after every css change (I make lot's of changes to my online site, about ten's in a day)... Clearing the cache ten's of times a day consumes too much life time for me and I really had enough of it.. Yes - Even if it is made by the **Admin Menu** module.

Is there any way to temporarily disable the cache or something of the sort?

Notes:
Screenshot of my Performance settings attached.

- Clicking ctrl+R never helps
- Clicking ctrl+F5 never helps

Comment: There's different layers of caching. Server side caching (Drupal) and Browser caching (Ctrl+R). They're totally separate. Ctrl+R won't affect what's coming back from the server.

Comment: @Beebee it can though. The browser sends a different request when Control R and Control F5 are pressed. So yes it can

Comment: @exussum yea you're right, to say it doesn't affect what comes back from the server is perhaps misleading, what I meant was it won't force Drupal to refresh its cache.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the `admin/config/development/performance` page under 'Bandwidth optimization' uncheck "Aggregate and compress CSS files.".

If you're looking for more control https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg/ is what you're looking for. Using the development setting in AdvAgg will detect the changes and push them out automatically.

Comment: Just the base module "Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation" needs to be installed to do what you want.

Comment: @ben AdvAgg works with aggregation turned on; sorry I didn't mention this. So on the `admin/config/development/performance` page turn on Bandwidth optimizations. Then on the `admin/config/development/performance/advagg` page put advagg into Development mode. Made a video for you as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=393XUGRhQks

Comment: Link to new question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/146805/css-js-aggregation-shuts-down-firebug-indication

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to make sure that you've disabled all caches and CSS aggregation in your Performance page.

Then you can activate 'Rebuild theme registry on every page.' option available in Theme development settings which you can find in Admin/Appearance for your default theme.

[image: Theme development settings]

Comment: Not every theme has this implemented.